# Is this actually using threading to scrape for urls?

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, python-multithreading

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm new to Python and trying to figure out how to use the threading module to scrape the NY Daily News site for urls. I put the following together and the script is scrapping but it doesn't seem to be any faster than it was before so I'm not sure the threading is happening. Can you let me know if it is? Can I write in anything so that I can tell? And also any other tips you have about threading?

Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urllib2
import os
import io
import threading

def fetch_url():
    for i in xrange(15500, 6100, -1):
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.nydailynews.com/search-results/search-results-7.113?kw=&tfq=&afq=&page={}&sortOrder=Relevance&selecturl=site&q=the&sfq=&dtfq=seven_years".format(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        snippet = soup.find_all('h2')
        for h2 in snippet:
            for link in h2.find_all('a'):
                logfile.write("http://www.nydailynews.com" + link.get('href') + "\n")
        print "finished another url from page {}".format(i)

with open("dailynewsurls.txt", 'a') as logfile:
    threads = threading.Thread(target=fetch_url())
    threads.start()
```

Comment: just how many urls are you trying to scrape? do you think the NYDN would like you running 500+ parallel requests on their site?

Comment: This code is using **one thread** (other than the main thread) to scrape the urls. That's not going to help. Use separate threads *per URL*.

Comment: If you do use separate threads per URL to scrape, you'll have to implement some kind of locking to write to your log file. You cannot just write to a file from separate threads without some kind of concurrency control. Witness the joke *"A programmer had a problem. He thought to himself, 'I know, I'll solve it with threads!'. has Now problems. two he"*

Comment: Martijn, thank you, I think that makes sense but I have zero clue how to do that. Do you mean a separate thread per url in the loop? Not per url being written to the logfile right?

Comment: Out of interest, is this by any chance on Linux?

Comment: @MartijnPieters or just use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module, whose handlers use locks to serialise access to their I/O.

Comment: `target=fetch_url()` is wrong; it should be `target=fetch_url` if you want the code to run inside the thread instead of outside of it before the thread is started. Not that that'll fix your problem...

Comment: @LukasGraf: I was thinking along the lines of [`multiprocess.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) but `logging` is fine too. Anything that abstracts the locking away should do.

Comment: @Martjin starting one thread per URL is a really, really bag idea - threads are expensive to create and need quite some memory. Also scheduling overheads will become a problem when you try to scrape thousand URLs at the same time too. A threadpool as provided by the multithreading module is the way to go.

Comment: @Voo, if you wanted to add an answer demonstrating it (rather than leaving some mechanism for limiting the number of concurrent threads as an exercise for the reader, as mine does), I'm sure such would be welcome. That said, I'm not sure the overhead of one-thread-per-URL (as opposed to the impact of running that entire set concurrently, which I did *not* see Martijn advocate except perhaps by omission) is as bad as you make it out to be; performance is still going to be bounded by network rather than CPU, making a bit of CPU-resource wastage affordable.

Comment: @Charles If you spawn one thread per URL, you are pretty much forced to have hundreds to thousands of threads lying around (image a page with hundreds of links). This will result in quite a bit of scheduling overhead and wasted resources for no reason. Heck on 32bit Windows the maximum number of threads you can create if your process does nothing else is just 2k threads - if you're unlucky scheduling wise (probably enough threads will finish before new ones are created, but there's no guarantee), your program will crash in that case.

Comment: @Voo, the number of threads "lying around" depends on one's batching strategy. Using a thread pool implicitly gives you a rolling strategy, which is optimal, but nothing Martijn or I have said indicates doing the silly/stupid thing of having one huge batch for thousands of URLs. Indeed, I explicitly tell the reader not to use my answer without making such an adjustment.

Comment: @Voo, ...and since I'm suggesting batching, that means explicitly using `join()` to ensure that threads complete between batches, so your claim that there's no guarantee isn't accurate. Again, though, I agree that a traditional rolling thread pool is the better implementation.

Comment: (As for "links" -- there's no recursion happening in the code the OP proposed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is a naive implementation (which will very quickly get you blacklisted from nydailynews.com):

```
def fetch_url(i, logfile):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.nydailynews.com/search-results/search-results-7.113?kw=&tfq=&afq=&page={}&sortOrder=Relevance&selecturl=site&q=the&sfq=&dtfq=seven_years".format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    snippet = soup.find_all('h2')
    for h2 in snippet:
        for link in h2.find_all('a'):
            logfile.write("http://www.nydailynews.com" + link.get('href') + "\n")
    print "finished another url from page {}".format(i)

with open("dailynewsurls.txt", 'a') as logfile:
    threads = []
    for i in xrange(15500, 6100, -1):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fetch_url, args=(i, logfile))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Note that `fetch_url` takes the number to substitute in the URL as an argument, and each possible value for that argument is started in its own, separate thread.

I would *strongly* suggest dividing the job into smaller batches, and running one batch at a time.

Comment: I'm pretty confident the OP would starve his own system's resources first before he makes a dent in the varnish sitting on http://www.nydailynews.com ;-)

Comment: Thank you!! Oddly, it runs well for a while - printing to the file and everything - and then says: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @JolijtTamanaha, I suspect that that happens because of the `with` clause's `exit` part running after all threads are started, not after all threads are exited. I'm moving the `t.join()` into that clause so we don't try to close the logfile until all threads have exited.

Comment: (err, meant `__exit__` handler).

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not using threads. `threads = threading.Thread(target=fetch_url())` calls `fetch_url()` in your main thread, *waits for it to complete* and passes its return value (`None`) to the `threading.Thread` constructor.

Comment: Actually answers the question asked; useful. :)